# How did B'nai Yisra'el differentiate what the departure of the cloud meant?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, behaalotcha-parsha

I'm curious about various functions of the cloud that rested on *Ohel Mo'ed*. For example:

In [Bemidbar 9:17 - 18](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14084&st=&pgnum=110) its says that B'nai Yisra'el would camp while the cloud was resting on the *Ohel Mo'ed*, and when it lifted, they would travel.

In [Bemidbar 12:10](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14084&st=&pgnum=148&hilite=) after G-d speaks to Aharon and Miriam, the cloud departs from the *Ohel*.

I assume that the conversation that G-d had with Aharon and Miriam was private. If B'nei Yisra'el saw the cloud depart from the Ohel, wouldn't that be a sign that they had to travel?

How would they know what the departure of the cloud meant? Was this a different cloud form? Was it located in a different area of the Ohel? What was happening?

**Note:** I am not asking specifically about how they knew when they should travel. I assume that the blowing of the trumpets was the main call to get ready, and if they didn't hear anything, then they knew not to travel. My question, here, is specifically if the placement or form of the cloud was different.

Comment: Did you look at the Targum - sometimes he translates very differently?

Comment: Also, do you think Bney Israel acted independently of Moses? Was it their call or Moses'? If it's about Moses the Q. would sound very different he would probably get some additional guidance.

Comment: @AlBerko Re Moshe getting involved - I had just realized that the trumpets were blown prior to their travelling. So, I think I have to edit this question a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Chumash Hamek Davar [Bemidbar 12:10] writes that this was a different cloud than the one that lifted when they traveled. He does however bring a Sporno that says it was the same cloud in  both cases, but everyone realised why it was lifting in the case of Miriam.